# TDD of android applications

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd

I need some advices and guidance related to TDD of android applications

I'm developing a complex android application (an automated robo player for a web game). Now i have a pilot for it, and before start continue with it's development, i want to make full TDD for it.

The main purpose of this application is run as a background service that communicates with a http server - it will send http requests with json content

It has to 2 modes of running:

```
- service mode - it will run in background- read some data configuration from database and communicate with the server 
- GUI mode - communication with server on demand + configuration for running in service mode.
```

GUI layer is designed as MVP, so all business done in a module (a MVP unit) is separated from view, therefore, all app logic is "NON android dependent".

I have several big layers that i need to make unit tests for:

```
- domain data access : 
      database storage (ormlite)
      android specific storage - shared prefs.., 
      files
- server communication - http client (spring android rest template)
                         http content conversion (gson)

- background services - android services
- GUI - activities
- app business - android independent - algorithms, computations, ...
```

In conclusion will need TDD - for every of these layers individually, but also integration tests for a complete flow.

tests included :

```
  - database DAO tests
  - http client requests 
  - GSON conversion TDDs
  - business logic - simple tests for methods
  - unit testsfor running and scheduled background services
  - activity unit testing
  - test suites (service + DAO + json conversion + http requests)
```

My first question is what TDD frameworks would be best for my needs? Should i use mocking or not ?

Please give me some directions to go for. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, for automatic testing : [junit](http://www.junit.org/).

---

For fluent assertions, you could look at [fest-assertions](https://github.com/nicstrong/fest-assertions-android). They provides a lot of examples, [here](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/fest-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/examples). But enjoy this one on the `String` :

```
 assertThat("Frodo").startsWith("Fro").endsWith("do").hasSize(5);
```

It isn't just harmonious, it increase also your productivity.

---

Since you want to write unit tests, you will have to write `mock` objects. Of course, you can do it without any framework, but it is **very** `tedious`.

Personnaly, i am big fan of [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). It's api is great and very fluent. Besides, you could the use the [BDDMockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/BDDMockito.html) static methods to write test in a [BDD](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) manner. Look :

```
//given  
given(seller.askForBread()).willReturn(new Bread());
//when
Goods goods = shop.buyBread();
//then
assertThat(goods, containBread());
```

Sometimes you will depend on class that you can't mock, for example a `final class` like [`BluetoothAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html). In these cases (and only in these), you could use [`PowerMock`](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).

Look also at this stuff :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336488/resources-for-tdd-on-android
- [Why Android isn’t ready for TDD, and how I tried anyway](
  http://daverog.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/why-android-isnt-ready-for-tdd-and-how-i-tried-anyway/)
- [Introduction to Android Testin](http://dtmilano.blogspot.fr/2011/08/linuxcon-2011-north-america.html)

There is also a book : [Android Application Testing Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/android-application-testing-guide/book)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned integration tests, you might also be interested in [RoboGherk](https://github.com/leandog/RoboGherk) as an automated acceptance testing framework for Android that was recently [announced by my friend at LeanDog](https://twitter.com/angelaharms/status/240893844365901824).